# How to suppress MQTT Last Will message if client reconnects?

Tags: arduino, mqtt, esp8266, mosquitto

I am using the EspMQTTClient library for Arduino and ESP8266; but my question may well be applicable to any environment.

The client sets a Last Will message for broadcast in the event that the client drops. However, if the client drops and then immediately reconnects, I want to suppress the message.

As the client unique ID is the same, I would've thought this would be standard behaviour; but apparently not.

So, the client drops, and reconnects. I get the startup messages the client sends, and *then* I get the Last Will "client has died" message. This is not helpful, as it looks like the client has died again and failed to reconnect.

How can I suppress Last Will messages for clients that successfully reconnect before the timeout occurs?

EDIT: Here is some simplified code that demonstrates the problem:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <EspMQTTClient.h>
#include "lwip/inet.h"
#include "lwip/dns.h"
#include "mqtt.h"
#include "secret.h"

#define SERVICE_NAME    "pc-control"

EspMQTTClient mqtt(SSID, PASSWORD, MQTT_SERVER, (String(SERVICE_NAME) + "/Example").c_str());;

void onConnectionEstablished() {
    mqtt.publish("Example", "ready");
}

void setup() {
    mqtt.enableLastWillMessage("Example", "dead", true);
}

void loop() {
    mqtt.loop();
    delay(100);
}
```

The problem seems to be related to the `String(SERVICE_NAME) + "/Example"` bit. I considered that perhaps it was creating a dangling pointer; but were that to be the cause, I would expect the LWT to occur even before the client lost connection.

I am running "mosquitto MQTT v3.1 message broker", and the subscriber looks like this:

```
mosquitto_sub -t "#" -v
Example ready
<<<I reset the client here>>>
Example ready
Example dead
```

Comment: Update the question with the client code and the version of mosquitto you are using

Comment: Also include details of the subscriber that is seeing the LWT being delivered after the reconnect message.

Comment: Is it perhaps that the service name is being seen as null at *all times*, due to a dangling pointer?

Comment: 3.1 is not the mosquitto version, that is the MQTT protocol version. The mosquitto version will be 1.x where X is most likely 5 or 6

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to suppress the Last Will & Testament (LWT)

But if you are sure you are using a consistent clientid I don't think it should be sending it. You said you are resetting the device, which means the broker sound be waiting 1.5 * the keep alive time then disconnecting the client. As long as devices reconnects with the same clientid before that happens or should evict the old connection without firing the LWT.

I cannot see where you set either the keep alive time or the clientid in the code you posted so it's hard to say more. I would also turn up the logging on the broker to check that the client is connecting with the same clientid and to see if it is evicting the previous client.

Answer (score 0):

If your broker following the MQTT v3.1.1 specification detects that you have disconnected, it is entirely correct to publish the LWT. There is no way to stop this.

@hardillb suggests that if the connection has gone down but not been noticed by the broker, then you have up to keepalive*1.5 to reconnect before the LWT is sent. This is correct. However, and this is a big however, you're relying on your loss of connection not being recognised at the broker. It might work sometimes, but it's not a condition I'd want to rely on.

If this feature is very important for you, then you probably should look at using MQTT v5 instead. That will give you the option of setting the "session expiry interval", which is the amount of time to keep your session active after you disconnect before sending your LWT.

Comment: I don't know if any of the embedded MQTT client libraries have been updated to support MQTT v5 yet

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, try upgrading to Mosquitto 1.6.3 or newer. There is a bug with session takeovers affecting 1.5.something to 1.6.2.